# VSTest.console Filter native c++ unit tests by attribute

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, vstest.console.exe

I'm currently running into the following problem:

We introduced Unit-Tests into our native c++ application by using the native microsoft unit test framework included in Visual Studio 2015 `Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework`.

To start the unit tests inside visual studio we use the `Test-Explorer` as can be seen in image 1. By adding a `method attribute` to a `Test-Method` (as shown in image 2) the `Test-Explorer` allows to sort and filter by attribute (as can be seen in image 3).

[image]

All this works without a problem. We started having a problem when we tried to implement these unit tests into our continous integration system (CI).

To start Unit-Tests from a console we use `vstest.console.exe`, which is located in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe`. The official documentation can be found [Here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155800.aspx)

The following screenshot shows how the tests succeed when using the console:
[image]

Adding a logger and outputing files to .trx works well too. What does **NOT** work however is applying a filter to determine tests with specific attributes. According to the documentation something like that should be possible by using the `/TestCaseFilter:`-switch. The following screenshot however shows the resulting error:

[image]

It translates to: *"No tests matched the filter because it contains one or more properties that are not valid (TakesLong). Specify filter expression containing valid properties (TestCategory, Priority, FullyQualifiedName, Name) and try again."*

Does anybody know this problem or has an idea on how to fix it? Ultimate goal is to be able to exclude certain tests (Take very long / need a hardware dongle etc.).

Best regards, LorToso

Comment: There is a nice write-up on unit testing with C++ using Test Explorer in VS, if you try this, can you use Text Explorer to filter your unit-tests? Here is the docs: 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270864.aspx

Comment: @PedroG.Dias Yes, I can use the test exploter to filter unit-tests. This does however not work when trying to run tests outside of visual studio (using the console)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too, and sadly it looks like we're just out of luck.  vstest.console.exe only supports a limited number of filters for both C++ and C#.

The approach I think I'm going to move towards is to segregate tests into different modules so I can run unit tests for nightly and CI builds and integration tests (like needing a database) only for releases.

Alternatively, you could split them up by namespace in the same module and use the FullyQualifiedName filter.  Unfortunately, there is no '!~' condition either so you might have to work around that somehow.